# Проверка на уникальность поля Asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Есть валидация на стороне клиента с помощью аннотаций ef core, но я не знаю как к этим проверками добавить проверку на уникальность имени пользователя. Посоветуйте что с этим можно сделать, пожалуйста.
Модель пользователя:

```
 public class User
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Не указан e-mail")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Не верный e-mail")]
    public string email { get; set; }
    public bool verifed { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage ="Не указано имя пользователя")]
    [StringLength(maximumLength:15,MinimumLength =5,ErrorMessage ="Имя пользователя должно содержать от 5 до 15 символов")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings =false, ErrorMessage = "Не указан пароль")]
    [StringLength(maximumLength: 15, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "Пароль должен содержать от 5 до 15 символов")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string  FirstName { get; set; }
    public string  LastName { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Не указан компания, это обазательное поле он необходимо для дальнейшей авторицации в приложении")]
    public string  Company { get; set; }
    public bool DemoAvaible { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }
    public Tenant Tenants { get; set; }
    public List<Payment> Payments { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать индекс и отметить, чтобы значение было уникальным с помощью атрибутов

```
 [Index("UserNameIndex", IsUnique = true)]
 public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Также можно это сделать и с помощью билдера:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<User>(entity => {
        entity.HasIndex(e => e.UserName).IsUnique();
    });
}
```

Надеюсь помог.

Comment: Насколько знаю в ef core нет аннотации Index